# Show that $\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x y=0\right\}$ it is not a locally Euclidean topological space.

Tags: general-topology

I have tried to reach a contradiction by working with the definition:

> $M$ is locally Euclidean of dimension $\boldsymbol{n}$ : each point of $M$ has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the following: I assumed that there exists an open set around $(0,0)$, let’s call it $U$. Then I defined $O = U - \{(0,0)\}$. Now, $O$ is not connected; in fact, it has 4 connected components. Does this somehow lead to an contradiction? And how can I determine that there is no homeomorphism to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ ?

Comment: Hint. Every open set in the plane is a union of open disks. Think about an open disk containing the origin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $xy=0$ is a variety but not a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018810/show-that-xy-0-is-a-variety-but-not-a-manifold) or this? [Why is this set not a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786876)

Comment: Or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280770/explain-why-this-set-is-not-a-differentiable-manifold/1285489

Comment: yes! thank you so much